# Is there an alternate way of getting the Masque of Clavicus Vile, apart from the quest "Daedra's Best Friend"?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I've been playing Skyrim a lot lately, and I just initiated the quest "Daedra's Best Friend". When I got to the shrine, I got the Rueful Axe, then came back and was given the choice of killing Barbas and keeping the axe, or sparing Barbas and giving the axe back, in which case I would get the Masque of Clavicus Vile.

I decided that I would not choose anything for the moment. I was planning to go back outside and use the Rueful Axe until I got something better, then I would come back and give the axe, receiving the Masque in exchange.

The only problem is that Barbas followed me outside, so I told him to stop following me, and so he just wandered aimlessly around the map. I completely forgot about the quest, and it was only ages later that I decided to go get my mask. Unfortunately, as I was walking through Whiterun, I found Barbas, dead, with three arrows in the chest. When I went to Clavicus, he just told me, "Good work, enjoy the axe."

I was kind of annoyed, since I want the Oblivion Walker achievement, but I couldn't load back, since I had made so much progress since the last time I saw Barbas and Clavicus.

Is there a way to get (or cheat) the mask? I'm playing Skyrim Special Edition on the Xbox One S.

Answer (score 5):

No, the masque is a unique daedric artifact, which can only be obtained by this quest. On PC you might use the console to cheat it in (though I doubt that would count for the achievement). On Xbox, you are pretty much limited to a mod, which gives you the masque (possibly also ignoring the achievement). I don't know whether such a thing exists.

Comment: Modding disables achievements by the way.

Comment: @IceC Don't think that's the case on PC, At least I have all the achievements and I haven't played without mods since release. May certainly be true on Xbox, yes.

Comment: There's a mod for PC that re-enables achievements when using mods.